# Java initialiase string from hex array

Tags: java, string, hex

Is it possible to initialize a String from an array of hex values, like C style?

```
unsigned char[] charArray = {0x41, 0x42, 0x43};
```

Why is not possible to do something like this?

```
String charArray = new String((byte[]) {0x41, 0x42, 0x43});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly possible, you can do it in several ways.

- Using unicode escapes:

  ```
  String string = "\u0041\u0042\u0043";
  ```
- Creating and using a byte array:

  ```
  String string = new String(new byte[] {(byte) 0x41, (byte) 0x42, (byte) 0x43});
  ```

The main thing you have to remember is that the string is not an array of something, it is a separate object. Therefore it should either be created as a string literal, or with one of the constructors.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't with `String`, it's with Java arrays and specifically bytes.

You can do

```
String charArray = new String(new byte[] {(byte) 0x41, (byte) 0x42,
  (byte) 0x43});
```

or, even better, you can just write the String more literally with ASCII escapes and the like.

```
"\u0041\u0042\u0043"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no unsigned types in Java, so your array must contain regular `char` values. However, numeric literals are by default of type `int`, so you may need to cast your values to `char`, like so: `(char)0x41`. Same goes for `byte` values (use one or the other depending on whether your numbers are ASCII or Unicode BMP values). You can also use the unicode escape, like `String str = "\u0041\u0042";`. To get a byte representation of an ASCII (or otherwise encoded) string (the opposite operation), use syntax such as: `String charArray = "abcd".getBytes("UTF-8");`.

Also, note the distinction between bytes and characters. A character is well-defined by Unicode standard and always has the same meaning. A byte's meaning depends on the character encoding used, so you can't just make a string out of bytes. If you use the `String(byte[])` constructor, you are using your platform's default encoding implicitly - this may be risky in some situations. `String(char[])` on the other hand is safe (but if you generate the `char` values by casting hex numbers to `char`s, you are de facto manually converting from ASCII).